# Is there any system permissions are required to unzip the files through Webservices at server side

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a scenario for unzip the files at server side using web services. I just upload the zip file to server. By using web service i have to unzip that file can any system permissions are required. Can any body give me a piece of code in C#

Comment: Can you give more details on the server machine?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously write permissions on the directory the file is unzipped to, write on the folder your web-service saves the zip file to when it's uploaded, and read on the zip file that's been saved to unzip it.

If you're after a zip component for C#, look at [SharpZibLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/) (open-source) or [Xceed Zip](http://xceed.com/Zip_Net_Intro.html) (commercial.)

Answer (score 0):

You'll basically need to have the account that the service is running under (ASPNET for example if under IIS) have permissions to write files for the directory you'r using

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the GZipStream in the System.IO.Compression namespace, there are no particular permission sets that you need to have granted in order to use it.

However, if you are persisting to disk, you identity the web service is running under (or the user connected to the web service, if you are impersonating them) most definitely need to have access to where you are writing the unzipped data.

On a side note, you should make sure that you are using the [Soap Message Transmission Optmimization Mechanism](http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-mtom/) if you are transferring large amounts of binary data across the line.